# Start the activity when it will open

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting an issue when i try to open my activity. Actually the state is i am calling an api  when i open the activity but when i minimize the application and open it again the home page is opening but the api is not calling again,so i have the doubt that how could run keep the same state when i will open the page the api should call.

I am calling the api inside oncreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//here i am calling the api

}
```

Could somebody help me @thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in onResume() method.
It is guaranteed to be called when the activity is shown. 
Needless to say that you will have to override onResume() method as well :)

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() is called when your activiy is **creating**. If you want to do work when activity is shown, you must do it in **onResume()**

For detailed information and lifecycle of activites: [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: @priya if it works, please check this as correct answer, so everybody could see easily.

Answer (score 0):

This explains the entire lifecycle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is only called for the first time when activity is created. Once you, minimize and again launch the application, onCreate wont be called. You can call your api from different place based on your need.

I think in your case you can call in the "**onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)".** This function is always called when window gains or looses focus. based on "hasFocus" value you can call the appi. You also may use onResume() which will be called when you activity resumes..

onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)" is the best way to do it..